# How to refresh different div in same page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am using `php` and `mysql` database for my website.

In my website I have `four` different menu. In that each menu have single div which has to refresh after clicking to it.

Here refresh mean it call php file which has functionality like insert,delete and display the specific contain from database.

My code is refreshing whole page instate of div refresh.

Here is my sample code:

My **mainpage.php**

```
<div>
            <ul id="headerMenu" class="menu">
        <li rel="menu1"><a href="" >About</a></li>



    <li rel="menu2"><a href="" class="">Display</a></li>

    <li rel="menu3"><a href="" class="">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="menu1" class="menu_content">
    <div class="right-pane">
        <div class="details">

<?php include('about.php'); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="menu2" class="menu_content">
    <div class="right-pane">
        <div class="details">

<?php include('display.php'); ?>
    </div>


    <div id="menu3" class="menu_content">
    <div class="right-pane">
        <div class="details">

   <?php include('Settings.php'); ?>
    </div>
```

My **display.php**

```
<?php

/* fetched latest data from database is done */


/* if i use header it going to main page about div */

?>
```

Now I want to display data in my display div.

Can any one please tell me how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: if you want to update only part of the page, you can use AJAX. jQuery provides a nice wrapper for it. [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Yep, it's the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Or you could use another jQuery ajax wrapper `$('#mydiv').load(URL)`  http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: can you please tell how to use this. sorry i am new to jQuery and ajax

Comment: I understood your problem as i have done this in past ( Correct me if I am wrong)

You are having 3 menu about , display & setting and on clicking each menu element the 

corresponding div should appear with it new content inside it. If such is the case then do respond

Comment: yes exactly i want that itself.

Comment: please can you help me on this how i can achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Try this code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $( "button[class='disp']" ).click(function() {
        $(".details").load('profile.php');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <ul id="headerMenu" class="menu">
        <li rel="menu1"><button>About</button></li>
        <li rel="menu2"><button class="disp">Display</button></li>
        <li rel="menu3"><button>Settings</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>

    <div id="menu1" class="menu_content">

    <div class="right-pane">
        <div class="about">
            <?php //include('about.php'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="menu2" class="menu_content">
        <div class="right-pane">
            <div class="details">
                <?php include('profile.php'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="menu3" class="menu_content">
        <div class="right-pane">
            <div class="Settings">
                <?php //include('Settings.php'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just add profile.php like that.

```
<?php echo rand(1, 9999); ?>
```

Do not forget to add JQuery.   http://jquery.com/download/

Hope it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: i used this in my java script. but it is not working. my code               $("li [class='menu3').click(function () {
    $(".details").load('myfile.php');
});

Comment: when i used this code after clicking to display menu again it loading and coming to about menu. what is the problem here.

Comment: I think you keep the same class name for about and display menu. So change the class name of about menu.

Comment: what i need is in whenever i click to display it has to come to display menu only. but it is going to about. is there any way to redirect to my mainpage in that display div should show.

Comment: I do not understand where you stuck, but if you need to redirect to your main page then you change jquery code and put the onclick function, redirection javascript code there.

Comment: thank you for your response. where i stuck is when i clicking on display menu its again going to the mainpage of about. not display.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily with ajax.

Example for one DIV:

```
<html>
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Ajax(){
    var xmlHttp;
        try{    
            xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// For Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari and Chrome
        }
        catch (e){
            try{
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // For Internet Explorer
            }
            catch (e){
                try{
                    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e){
                    alert("No AJAX!!!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
            setTimeout('Ajax()',10000);
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET","http://www.examplepage.com/the_page_that_contains_the_div_content",true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    }

    window.onload=function(){
        setTimeout('Ajax()',10000);
    }
    </script>

    <div id="ReloadThis">Default text</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: As it is tagged with jQuery, it would be more concise to use it

Comment: thank you. but i am not getting how to call dynamically xmlHttp.open because i have 3 php files.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your functionality in php together print it in json format `json_encode(outputdatafromphp);` get that value from your ajax function in javascript and make your menu div tag as clickable inside the success function

`

```
$.ajax({
url:url,
type:'post',
dataType:'json',
success:function(out){  
 $('#menu1').click(out,function(){
   $.each(out,function(ie,value){
       alert(value.data);
}

}
$('#menu2').click(out,function(){
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.menu_content').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $menu_to_load=$(this).children('.right-pane .details')
    $menu_to_load.load( $menu_to_load.attr('id'));
});
/*make sure your div with class "detail" have id of the page you want to call for them */
```

Answer (score -1):

What lbu said.

Use $.ajax to do a call to a php program that will return the data you want. for this example, hold it in var ajax_data

On .success event of ajax call, stuff the contents into the correct div like this:

```
<!-- html definition of display div -->
<div id="displaystuff"></div>

...
// script: 
$('#displaystuf').html(ajax_data)
```

Answer (score -1):

PHP is on the server side, so it can only generates "pages",.. If you want to modify the content of a "page" without refresh the page itself, you have to use javascript to make ajax request. So you can insert a php response in the HTMLElement you want.

It's easyer with jQuery. 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/